# Empty spaces on jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to build a sort of image gallery for my client's products, so that he can edit, delete and add images related to each product when editing it without having to reload the page on each request (using ajax).

Everything works fine, except for this : [alt text http://filipematias.aeon-dev.org/grwefdws.jpg](http://filipematias.aeon-dev.org/grwefdws.jpg)

As you can see in the image above, I have space for 3 images (wich is the limit in this case)
, and, for example, when I delete the first one and add a new one, I't will delete the markup of the first and add the second markup with jQuery append() function. The problem is that it lets an empty space on the left side of the image group, wich will cause the div to expand wrong, and I need it to have only that size. Think you get the idea.

Does anyone know how to clear that empty space with jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I was deleting the markup elements using remove() function but apparently  I wasn't removing the main container of the image, just the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be CSS problem... (if I understand all) so show us CSS.
Try to use web-developer tool to check generated source of your jquery script.

Comment: each image container inside the main container is set to float at the left, but it ain't working. Setting the white-space css property didn't work as well.